# Reading JSON data with nested obects within arrays to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

I'm stuck trying to read the below JSON data into SQL Server 2016. I can't return any values from the `Values` object onwards.

The select statement shows NULL values for `binWidth`, `minVal`, `nBins` and `type`.

Also, I'm unsure how to deal with the result array as the values do not have any keys assigned.

Any help much appreciated.

JSON data:

```
DECLARE @json   NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'{
  "Histograms": [
    {
      "Name": "20458-Z01-DWL",
      "RegisterId": "0",
      "Tags": [],
      "UUID": "a4c5fa3f-ecb8-4635-8e94-5167e743b518",
      "Values": [
        {
          "config": {
            "binWidth": 50,
            "minVal": 50,
            "nBins": 18,
            "type": "total wait"
          },
          "result": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "20458-Z02-DWL",
      "RegisterId": "1",
      "Tags": [],
      "UUID": "95d57826-30f6-44c9-ad0d-6a24684fcaed",
      "Values": [
        {
          "config": {
            "binWidth": 50,
            "minVal": 50,
            "nBins": 18,
            "type": "total wait"
          },
          "result": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "20458-Z03-DWL",
      "RegisterId": "2",
      "Tags": [],
      "UUID": "90223a0e-3d1a-471f-a871-ee56da4799f5",
      "Values": [
        {
          "config": {
            "binWidth": 50,
            "minVal": 50,
            "nBins": 18,
            "type": "total wait"
          },
          "result": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "20458-Z04-DWL",
      "RegisterId": "3",
      "Tags": [],
      "UUID": "6c837def-feeb-48d5-8dcf-307b56ec44e9",
      "Values": [
        {
          "config": {
            "binWidth": 50,
            "minVal": 100,
            "nBins": 16,
            "type": "total wait"
          },
          "result": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "20458-Z05-DWL",
      "RegisterId": "4",
      "Tags": [],
      "UUID": "76bd5aa2-8860-4a2e-997d-3c83e940790f",
      "Values": [
        {
          "config": {
            "binWidth": 50,
            "minVal": 100,
            "nBins": 16,
            "type": "total wait"
          },
          "result": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "LogEntryId": 6593,
  "StartTimestamp": "2020-07-20T16:05:00Z",
  "Timestamp": "2020-07-20T16:06:00Z"
}'
```

Query to fetch items from data:

```
SELECT 
    [Name],
    [RegisterId],
    UUID,
    binWidth
    minVal,
    nBins,
    [type]
FROM 
    OPENJSON (@json, '$.Histograms') 
    WITH 
        ([Name] nvarchar(100), 
         [RegisterId] nvarchar(100),
         UUID nvarchar(100),
         [Values] nvarchar(max) AS json) AS Histograms
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON (Histograms.[Values])
    WITH
        (binWidth int,
         minVal int,
         nBins int,
         [type] nvarchar(100)) AS config
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the last question re. passing result array into one field - edit below. Thanks again for your guidance, have learnt a lot!

```
select 
  Histograms.[Name],
  Histograms.[RegisterId],
  Histograms.UUID,
  config.binWidth,
  config.minVal,
  config.nBins,
  config.[type],
  r.[key] as 'result position',
  r.[value] as 'result value'
from
  openjson(@json, '$.Histograms')
    with (
      [Name] nvarchar(100), 
      LogEntryId int,
      [RegisterId] nvarchar(100),
      UUID nvarchar(100),
      [Values] nvarchar(max) as json
    ) as Histograms
  cross apply openjson (Histograms.[Values]) h
  cross apply openjson (h.value)
    with
    (
      binWidth int N'$.config.binWidth',
      minVal int N'$.config.minVal',
      nBins int N'$.config.nBins',
      [type] nvarchar(100) N'$.config.type',
      result nvarchar(max) as json
    ) as config 
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(config.result) r
```